# Django - cannot unpack non-iterable ManyRelatedManager object

Tags: django

so I'm trying to display a list of items from a table that don't appear in another table.  But I keep getting errors such as "cannot unpack non-iterable ManyRelatedManager object"

I've tried many variations of django filter and exclude but there is always an error of either the aforementioned or depending on other things I have tried:
User object has no attribute profile
or
Cannot unpack non-iterable int object

Models:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.item_name
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Item"
        verbose_name_plural = "Items"



class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user") 
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Profile"
        verbose_name_plural = "Profiles"
```

Views:

```
python
@login_required
def item_view(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
    user_obj = request.user.user
        items = Item.objects.filter(user_obj.items)
        context_dict = {'items': items}
        return render(request, 'site/items.html', context_dict)
    else:
        return HttpResponseNotFound()
```

items.html:

```
{% for i in items%}
      <li><input type="checkbox" data-pk="{{i.pk}}" name="{{i.item_name}}" value="{{i.pk}}" onchange="processChange(this)"> {{i.item_name}}<br>
      </li>
{% endfor %}
```

The goal is for items.html to display all the items that are not in the users profile.  Everything I seem to try doesn't seem to work so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace:

```
items = Item.objects.filter(user_obj.items)
```

With:

```
user_items = Items.objects.filter(profile=user_obj)
items = Items.objects.exclude(pk__in=user_items)
```

`user_items` will contain a queryset with all `Item` objects related to the `User` in `user_obj`.

`items` will contain a queryset with all `Item` objects, **excluding** the ones that are related to the `User` in `user_obj`

You were getting your error because `filter()` needs a field from a model:

- `filter(user='some user')`

More information about how to make queries can be read in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/)

Comment: When I try this I get the error: 
Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field. Choices are: item_name, id, profile

Comment: Ok I fixed it by changing user_items = Items.objects.filter(user=user_obj)
To
user_items = Items.objects.filter(profile=user_obj)

Works perfectly now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

try using:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_list_or_404

items = get_list_or_404(Item, user=user_obj)
```

if that doesn't work, trying uing,

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

items = get_object_or_404(Item, user=user_obj)
```

Comment: Also, your spacing is off. Tab over 'user_obj', though I'm assuming that was just a typo, and not an error with your code.

Comment: Trying this gets the same error as the other answer:
Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field. Choices are: item_name, id, profile